# how can I refresh something each sec?

Tags: html, setinterval, document.write

I 'd writen something on the screen with setinterval(), and the results are queueing on the screen. I want to refresh it every seconds and have just one on the screen at a time. Any ideas?
setInterval("display()",1000);

Comment: I think we will need a little more context here. Replacing html-contents is the easy part of it, getting the updated information might be hard, but is really problem specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `iframe` or `object` to load a document,

```
<iframe src="seconder.html"></iframe>
<object data="seconder.html"></object>
```

which includes a `meta` refresh pragma:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <!--One second meta refresh--> 
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1">
  </head>
  <body>
     <!--
     ...
     ...
     -->
  </body>
 </html>
```

**References**

- [http-equiv meta attribute](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/meta)
- [HTTP Response Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917918.aspx)
- [HTML Elements: Meta](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/meta)
- [Beginner's guide to Meta Tags](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2494/Beginner-s-guide-to-Meta-Tags)
- [Meta tags that Google understands](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812)
- [konqueror/meta_tag_refresh_test.html at master · KDE/konqueror](https://github.com/KDE/konqueror/blob/master/webenginepart/testfiles/meta_tag_refresh_test.html)